# Find a coordinate vector of a dual basis in a polynominal vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have problems with the dual space and the dual basis.

Let $V := Span(T^0,...,T^n)\subseteq \mathbb{C}[T]$ be a finite vector space and $B =(T^0,...,T^n)$ be the standard basis for $V$. Then there is a transformation 
$$
D_z: V\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}; \sum_{k=0}^n (a_kT^k) \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^n (ka_k z^{k-1}) $$

I already showed that $D_z$ is a linear transformation but now i need to find the coordinate vector $x_{B^{*}}(D_z)$ of the dual basis $B^* = ((T^0)^*,...,(T^n)^*)$

I don't even know how a coordinate vector of a transformation looks like. 
I want to find a $x_{B^{*}}(D_z)$ so that $x_{B^{*}}(D_z) * B^* = D_z$ but how is a multiplication of two vectors a transformation?

The transformation does for example:

$(a_0T^0 + a_1T^1 + a_2T^2) \mapsto (a_1z^0+2a_2z^1)$ or in general:
$(a_0T^0 + a_1T^1+...+ a_nT^n) \mapsto (a_1z^0+2a_2z^1+...+na_nz^{n-1})$

Somehow I think $x_{B^{*}}(D_z) = (a_1z^0,2a_2z^1,...,na_nz^{n-1},0)$

but i am really not sure and would like to know how to calculate $x_{B^{*}}(D_z)$

Comment: When things get confusing, appeal to definitions, describe things more carefully, and write things out more carefully. I can't actually make sense of your problem as you've formulated it -- and if you've put the problem in a way that doesn't make sense, that can explain why you're having trouble making sense of the problem! (I could substitute some new problem I might consider with this data, and it might even be the problem you're trying to describe, but that's not something I can confirm or deny based on what you've written)

Comment: @Hurkyl sorry for the missunderstandings. I tried to express the task in the best way possible. Maybe the task itself is missleading. I'll try better next time.

Answer (score 1):

If we have $p=\sum_{k=0}^na_kT^k$, then by linearity $$D_zp=\sum_{k=0}^na_kD_zT^k.\tag{1}$$ That is, $D_z$ is completely determined by its action on the basis vectors $T^k$. Recall that the dual basis $B^*$ of $B$ is a basis $\{f_k\}$ of $V^*$ such that $f_jT^k=\delta_j^k$. If we expand $D_z$ as $\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha^kf_k$, we then have $$D_zp=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\sum_{j=0}^n\alpha^jf_jT^k=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\sum_{j=0}^n\delta_k^j\alpha^j=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha^k a_k.\tag{2}$$ This last sum can be written as $$(\alpha^0,\dots,\alpha^n)(a_0,\dots,a_n)^T.$$ The column vector on the right you will recognize as the coordinate representation of $p$ relative to $B$. Similarly, the row vector on the left is the coordinate representation of $D_z$ relative to $B^*$. Comparing the last sum in equation (2) to (1), we can see that $\alpha^k=D_zT^k$, that is, the $B^*$-coordinates of $D_z$ are its actions on the basis vectors $T^k$ of $B$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I would pick a different letter than $T$ for a variable denoting an arbitrary element of $V$. Especially so since $T$ has already been given a meaning.

Comment: @Hurkyl I considered that, but followed the OPs notation for the basis vectors.